# Inconvergencia de resultados consolidado x por intervalo

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou fazendo uma consulta por intervalo de 10 minutos entre data, o problema é que quando eu dou um between para contar todos os resultados ele retorna um valor e quando eu divido esses valores por intervalo e somo no final ele da sempre um resultado total maior, será que é um bug do mysql?

**CONSOLIDADO:**

```
    SELECT 
   sum(case when c.id_queue_call_entry = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as  FILA_700, 
   sum(case when c.id_queue_call_entry = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as  FILA_704, 
   sum(case when c.id_queue_call_entry = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as  FILA_705, 
   sum(case when c.id_queue_call_entry = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as  FILA_708, 
   sum(case when c.id_queue_call_entry = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as  FILA_707, 
   sum(case when c.id_queue_call_entry = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as  FILA_709, 
   COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM
    call_center.call_entry c
WHERE
    datetime_entry_queue BETWEEN '2016-11-03 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-03 23:59:59'  ;
```

**COM INTERVALO:**

```
---- mesma consulta
      WHERE
        datetime_entry_queue BETWEEN '2016-11-03 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-03 00:10:00'  ;
---- mesma consulta
      WHERE
            datetime_entry_queue BETWEEN '2016-11-03 00:10:00' AND '2016-11-03 00:20:00'  ;
---- mesma consulta
      WHERE
            datetime_entry_queue BETWEEN '2016-11-03 00:20:00' AND '2016-11-03 00:30:00'  ;
```

*Estou fazendo a consulta direto no banco para testar.

[imagem banco total](https://postimg.org/image/aj5hzt8un/)

[imagem intervalo](https://postimg.org/image/5j81rv37z/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve fazer a consulta sempre considerando o máximo do período anterior, ou seja, descontando 1 segundo do final:

```
...WHERE datetime_entry_queue BETWEEN '2016-11-03 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-03 00:09:59';
```

Você pode fazer isso utilizando a função `SUBTIME`:

```
...WHERE datetime_entry_queue BETWEEN '2016-11-03 00:00:00' AND SUBTIME('2016-11-03 00:10:00', '0 0:0:1.00000'));
```

> A função SUBTIME do MySQL retorna um valor `time` ou `datetime` depois que um certo intervalo de tempo é removido.

[MySQL: SUBTIME Function](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/subtime.php)

Comment: vlw @Sorack, é isso mesmo, salvo minha cabeça kkkk